# How to change the background color of dropdown list in select tag?

Tags: php, select, html-select, background-color, dropdown

I am working on a website in which I am fetching the data from the database 
by using the following php code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
        <?php
        foreach($data['hellos'] as $hello) {
            echo '<option value="'.$hello->hello_id.'">'.$hello->name.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

In the above php code, **hellos** is the table name and **name** is the name of column present in that table. The **name column** has around 10-15 elements.

The above PHP is creating a dropdown (**it is just a snippet, it has around 10-15 elements as stated above**) at the front-end as shown below:

[image]

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what CSS codes I need to add so that I can change the **background color having those 2 elements (Homes and Entertainment) as shown in the image above**.

The CSS code which I have used in order to change the background color is:

```
select option {
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the background color of the 2 given option ?

Comment: Yes but it can be more than 2 depending how much items are present in the table in that column.

Comment: I am not sure about the question, so it will be great, if you can make me clear, there are few options in your dropdown, do you want to add background colour to few of them or to all?The numbers of options are constant or are changing?if changing?with ajax or page load? I have such questions on it.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean by changing only the 2 option's background ?

```html
<select>
<option></option>
<option style = 'background-color:green;'>Homes</option>
<option style = 'background-color:green;'>Entertainment</option>
<option>Others</option>
</select>
```

On your php you can apply this like

```
 <select class="form-control" id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
    <?php
    foreach($data['hellos'] as $hello) {
        $match = array('Homes','Entertainment');
        $color = (in_array($hello->id, $match)) ? " style = background-color:green; " : "";
        echo "<option value='".$hello->hello_id."' " . $color . ">".$hello->name."</option>";
    }
    ?>
```

**UPDATE**
Given you just want to change the background color of your option just add an inline style in your option

```
<select class="form-control" id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
    <?php
    foreach($data['hellos'] as $hello) {
        echo "<option value='".$hello->hello_id."' style = background-color:green;>".$hello->name."</option>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: No no. Not only the 2 options. It can be any number of elements present in that column in the table.

Comment: I have edited my question. Hopefully, it will make sense now.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't explain my question properly. I don't think so we can use the code above as it is specific to two elements only.

Comment: @jerome, there should be `$hello->name` in `in_array($hello->name, $match)`

Comment: @user5447339 just having trouble to understand you. if you want all of the options to have a background color why not just use a plain inline css inside your option tag ?

Comment: @jerome  Tried with this but it doesn't seem to work `echo '<option style="background-color:red;" value="'.$hello->hello_id.'">'.$hello->name.'</option>';`

Comment: use `'<option style=background-color:red; value="'.$hello->hello_id.'">'.$hello->name.'</option>'` remove the double quotes in style

Comment: @jerome Tried. No change in background color.

Comment: @jerome Didn't work still. Not sure why I can't change the color. I have a genuine feeling that it Is a browser issue ?

Comment: @user5447339 what browser are you using ? Have you tried checking / removing your classes and id. Maybe it has CSS in it

Comment: I would not write `$match = array('Homes','Entertainment');` inside of the loop.  There is no benefit to re-declaring it _n_ times.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select class="form-control" id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
        <?php
        $ArrData = ["homes","entertainment"];
        foreach($data['hellos'] as $hello) {
            $slectedColor = (in_array(strtolower($hello->name), $ArrData )) ? 'class="green"' : '';
            echo '<option value="'.$hello->hello_id.'" '.$slectedColor.'>'.$hello->name.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

Example html:

```
<select class="test">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option class="white">Option 2</option>
    <option class="green">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
select {
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}

select * {
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}

select *.green {
    background:green;
    color:#fff;
}

select *.white {
    background:#fff;
    color:#000;
}
```

Live example: https://codepen.io/measan/pen/OwdxXq

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the background color to dynamic values then you should store that values in the database and get at the time of listing in the drop-down.
If you want to apply on specific values then you should define that values in an array.

```
<select class="form-control" id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
        <?php
        $ArrData = ["homes","entertainment"];
        foreach($data['hellos'] as $hello) {
            $slectedColor = (in_array(strtolower($hello->name), $ArrData )) ? 'style="background:#fffff;"' : '';
            echo '<option value="'.$hello->hello_id.'" ".$slectedColor.">'.$hello->name.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gufran. I have edited my question. If you read my question, it is not specific to only 2 elements.

Comment: Okay, put that value in array list on which you want to apply background color.

Comment: elements can be infinite. I can't put any specific value. Can we do through CSS like the way I tried ?

Comment: I think you should set and get that dynamic values in database

Comment: otherwise there should be some specific logic or trick through which we would apply background color.

Comment: I tried with jerome code above but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I have a feeling it is some browser issue.

Comment: Did try this one?

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to achive this via css , you could assign an id to your select statement ,after which in css file , access that select id and assign the color you wish to

```css
#select_1 {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<select id="select_1" class="form-control" id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
 <option>
 <option >Homes</option>
 <option >Entertainment</option>
 <option>Others</option>
 </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a function that will return random color like this one

```
    function generateRandomColor()
    {
        $color = '#';
        $colorLighter = array("9","A","B","C","D","E","F" );
        for($x=0; $x < 6; $x++){
            $color .= $colorLighter[array_rand($colorLighter, 1)]  ; 
             }            
        return substr($color, 0, 7);
    }
```

And in your options you need to call this function instead of giving color code.Some thing like this

```
$slectedColor = (in_array(strtolower($hello->name), $ArrData )) ? 'style="background:".$this->generateRandomColor(). : '';
```

You can write the code as you want

Answer (score 0):

So as i understand you have a table with 10 - 15 contents in them,
these are shown as menu i am guessing, and you need to show some in different color,

If that is right and if you have a way to distinguish them like a variable in the array that points to it then yes it is possible.

(If 'color_pointer' is 1 then the color is green).

**CSS**

```
.color_green {
  background:green;
  color: Brown;
}
.color_normal {
  background:white;
  color: Black
}
```

---

** PHP **

```
$data['hellos'] = array(
array('name' => 'Home','color_pointer' => 1,...),
array('name' => 'Entertainment','color_pointer' => 1,... ),
array('name' => 'contact','color_pointer' => 0,... ),
);

<select class="form-control" id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
    <?php
    foreach($data['hellos'] as $hello) {
     if($hello->color_pointer == 1) {
        echo '<option class="color_green" value="'.$hello->hello_id.'">'.$hello->name.'</option>';
     } else {
        echo '<option class="color_normal" value="'.$hello->hello_id.'">'.$hello->name.'</option>';
     }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are close to answer yourself:

```
select option {
    background: white;
}
```

but you need to do it like that:

```
select>option:first-child, select>option:nth-child(2) {
    background: white; /*or any other color*/
}
```

Also it will be a good idea to add a class or id to the select.